# Cron script error on the server

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I have a Linux server and I am trying to run this script as a cron, it use to run fine but lately I am getting this error
Output from command http://xx.xxx.1xx.xx/planner/migration.php ..

/bin/sh: http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/planner/migration.php: No such file or directory

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether that file exists or not at this location: `http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/planner/migration.php`

Comment: It does! When I run it manually by typing it in. It runs perfectly. It's just that the cron says it can't find it.

Comment: See this: http://www.unix.com/302351513-post2.html and http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/. Also you need to put php in front of the command i.e.
`php path/to/php.file`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that every user has a different crontab. Maybe you are running your script from the crontab of a different user that doesn't have permission to read that file.

Cheers!

Comment: I have tried the root and most users that have universal permissions. Still wont work!